Kubernetes Routing ingress file
we have a use case where we have to route the api for different svc based on the ID passed in the URL, i.e. if
this is the use case but not working
the routing should be like if request came to hello.domain.com/hello-service/v1/organisations/4999c9f1/(.) then it should route to hello-setup-svc and if request comes to hello.domain.com/hello-service/v1/organisations/77777/(.) then it should route to hi-setup-svc

Both requests look the same

yes... sorry my bad.. now its updated
